# Reading data from a serial Port DataReceived Method in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing an a program to read from a serial port device. when accept key is clicked on the device it writes data to the serial port.But i'm getting some unreadable string as output

```
N?N?{w?¦?g?o?s?~?o?N?s?s?s?nN?N?c{{?O^L_?¦?s?s?N?c{s?N?s?{?o?s?N?~?g?^w?f?g?¦?{?
```

I have tried all possible string, byte, hex conversion method i can but to no avail. Here is some parts of my source code in c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM8");
        //var p = new Program();
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 2400;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 7;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
        //mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        //mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        mySerialPort.PinChanged += new SerialPinChangedEventHandler(PinChangedHandle);
         mySerialPort.Open();

    }

 private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            //Get the number of bytes data in the receive buffer
            byte[] indata = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];

            //Get the buffer size
            int dataSize = sp.ReadBufferSize;

           // Console.Write(sp.ReadExisting());

            //Read byte and write bytes into indata
            sp.Read(indata, 0, indata.Length);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(indata.Length*2);

            foreach (byte b in indata)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}", Convert.ToChar(b));
            }
            Console.Write(sb.ToString());
            writeToLog(sb.ToString()); // writes to a text file

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.Read();

        }

    }
```

I need help. I don't know if anyone had scaled through similar experience and is willing to help out... i'll really appreciate

Comment: This could look like a baud rate issue, but first you should fix a bit in your receiving code. It seems like you're trying to read extra bytes, as you're doing a read of indata.Length instead of the datasize you just assigned. Also could try to do Encoding.ASCII.ToString instead of using the string buffer, if you're transmitting in ASCII format.

Comment: @Jesper thanks for your response, The baudrate 2400bps is manufaturer's specification from the device documentation

Comment: At such a low baudrate a device almost always sends binary data instead of text.  So blindly converting bytes to characters is just going to produce nonsense.  If the manual doesn't explain enough about the protocol that the device uses then give the manufacturer a call.

Comment: @Jesper and Hans thanks for your comments i actually did change the baudrate from 2400bps to 9600bps and it worked fine :-) Thanks a lot